# Не работает hasClass()

Tags: jquery, javascript

Привет всем. Помогите ...
Функция hasClass() выдает false, хотя класс есть.
Весь код ниже ...

```
alert($(event.target).hasClass('.term_li'));
alert($(event.target).attr('class'));

$('.main').on('click', '.term_li, .page_link, .filter_active_close, .block_button, .line_button', function  (event) {
        var wrap_type = $('.empty_block');
        var category_id = wrap_type.attr('data-category');
        var type = wrap_type.attr('data-type');
        var send_mas = '';
        var ot1 = '';
        var do1 = '';
        var number = wrap_type.attr('data-number');

        /// greed
        if ($(this).hasClass('block_button')) {
            alert('block');
            type: 'greed';
            wrap_type.removeClass('line').addClass('greed').fadeOut(400).empty()
            $('#line_but').removeClass('act');
            $(this).addClass('act');
            setCookie('wrap_cat_type', 'greed', { path: '/' });
        }

        /// line
        if ($(this).hasClass('line_button')) {
            alert('line');
            type = 'line';
            wrap_type.removeClass('greed').addClass('line').fadeOut(400).empty();
            $('#block_but').removeClass('act');
            $(this).addClass('act');
            setCookie('wrap_cat_type', 'line', { path: '/' });
        }

        alert($(event.target).hasClass('.term_li'));
        alert($(event.target).attr('class'));

        if ( $(event.target).hasClass('.term_li') ) {
            alert('term');
            var active_wrap = $('#active_filters');

            if ($(this).tagName == 'LI') {
                var cur_obj = $(this);
                cur_obj.toggleClass('click');
            }
            else if ($(this).tagName == 'INPUT') {
                var cur_obj = $(this).parent();
                cur_obj.addClass('click');
                if (($('.ot_input').val() == 0) && ($('.do_input').val() == 0)) {
                    cur_obj.removeClass('click');
                }
            }

            var step_count = 0;
            active_wrap.removeClass('hide').empty();

            var f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7 = false;
            var mas = [
                [''],
                [''],
                [''],
                [''],
                [''],
                [''],
                ['']
            ];
            var v1, v2 = 0;

            $('.click', '#filter').each(function (i) {
                step_count = i.count;
                var cur_item = $(this);
                var parent_obj = $(this).parent();
                if (parent_obj.hasClass('term_manufacturer')) {
                    if (!f1) {
                        mas[0] = '<div id="manufacturer" class="filter_active_item"><span class="title_filter_active_item">Производитель</span>'
                    }
                    f1 = true;
                    mas[0] += '<span id="' + cur_item.attr("id").substr(4) + '" class="name_filter_active_item">' + cur_item.text() + '<i class="filter_active_close"></i></span>'
                } else if (parent_obj.hasClass('term_condition')) {
                    if (!f2) {
                        mas[1] = '<div id="condition" class="filter_active_item"><span class="title_filter_active_item">Состояние</span>'
                    }
                    f2 = true;
                    mas[1] += '<span id="' + cur_item.attr("id").substr(4) + '" class="name_filter_active_item">' + cur_item.text() + '<i class="filter_active_close"></i></span>'
                } else if (parent_obj.hasClass('term_caliber')) {
                    if (!f3) {
                        mas[2] = '<div id="caliber" class="filter_active_item"><span class="title_filter_active_item">Калибр</span>'
                    }
                    f3 = true;
                    mas[2] += '<span id="' + cur_item.attr("id").substr(4) + '" class="name_filter_active_item">' + cur_item.text() + '<i class="filter_active_close"></i></span>'
                } else if (parent_obj.hasClass('term_descent')) {
                    if (!f4) {
                        mas[3] = '<div id="descent" class="filter_active_item"><span class="title_filter_active_item">Спуск</span>'
                    }
                    f4 = true;
                    mas[3] += '<span id="' + cur_item.attr("id").substr(4) + '" class="name_filter_active_item">' + cur_item.text() + '<i class="filter_active_close"></i></span>'
                } else if (parent_obj.hasClass('term_destination')) {
                    if (!f5) {
                        mas[4] = '<div id="destination" class="filter_active_item"><span class="title_filter_active_item">Предназначение</span>'
                    }
                    f5 = true;
                    mas[4] += '<span id="' + cur_item.attr("id").substr(4) + '" class="name_filter_active_item">' + cur_item.text() + '<i class="filter_active_close"></i></span>'
                } else if (parent_obj.hasClass('term_number')) {
                    if (!f6) {
                        mas[5] = '<div id="number_of_barrels" class="filter_active_item"><span class="title_filter_active_item">Количество стволов</span>'
                    }
                    f6 = true;
                    mas[5] += '<span id="' + cur_item.attr("id").substr(4) + '" class="name_filter_active_item">' + cur_item.text() + '<i class="filter_active_close"></i></span>'
                } else if ($(this).hasClass('price_wrap')) {
                    mas[6] = '<div id="price2" class="filter_active_item"><span class="title_filter_active_item">Цена</span>'
                    v1 = parseInt($('.ot_input', $(this)).val());
                    v2 = parseInt($('.do_input', $(this)).val());
                    var text = '';
                    if (v1 == 0) {
                        text = 'до ' + v2;
                    }
                    else if (v2 == 0) {
                        text = 'от ' + v1;
                        v2 = 1000000000;
                    }
                    else if ((v1 != 0) && (v2 != 0)) {
                        text = v1 + ' - ' + v2;
                    }
                    mas[6] += '<span id="price" class="name_filter_active_item">' + text + '<i class="filter_active_close"></i></span>'
                }

            });

            if (step_count == 0) {
                active_wrap.addClass('hide')
            }
            active_wrap.append(mas[0] + '</div>' + mas[1] + '</div>' + mas[2] + '</div>' + mas[3] + '</div>' + mas[4] + '</div>' + mas[5] + '</div>' + mas[6] + '</div>');

            var data = [];
            $('.filter_active_item', '#active_filters').each(function (k1, obj) {
                var mas_id = [];
                $('.name_filter_active_item', $(this)).each(function (k2, obj2) {
                    if ($(this).attr('id') != 'price') {
                        mas_id[k2] = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
                    }
                });
                data[k1] = {
                    taxonomy: $(this).attr('id'),
                    field: 'id',
                    terms: mas_id
                }
            });

            send_mas = data;
            ot1 = v1;
            do1 = v2;
        }

        if ($(this).hasClass('.filter_active_close')) {
            alert('close');
            var obj_id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
            if (obj_id == 'price') {
                $('.ot_input').val(0);
                $('.do_input').val(0);
                $('#termprice').removeClass('click');
            }
            $("#term" + obj_id).click();
        }

        if ($(this).hasClass('.page_link')) {
            alert('page');
            number = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0].substr(4);
        }

        alert('prosto');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajax_data_object.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: 'universal',
                category: category_id,
                type: type,
                mas: send_mas,
                ot1: ot1,
                do1: do1,
                number: number
            },
            dataType: 'html',
            error: function() {
                wrap_type.text('Update failed. Try again.').slideDown('slow');
            },
            success: function(res_data) {
                wrap_type.html(res_data);
            }
        });

        $("#loading").ajaxStart(function () {
            $(this).fadeIn(400);
        });

        $("#loading").ajaxSuccess(function (evt, request, settings) {
            $(this).fadeOut(400);
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У [`.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

аргумент - имя класса, а не селектор. т.е. надо `.hasClass('term_li')`

если хотите селектор, то используйте [`.is()`](https://api.jquery.com/is/)

Comment: сори, просто голова уже не варит, 
нужен бил свежий взгляд)
спасибо. очень помогли

Comment: сам на себя зол, как такое не заметил ...
на Ваш взгляд код можно как то по другому записать ...
или так норм ?

Comment: @crymaks не знаю, не вникал, но на вскидку - 

 * вместо `.attr('data-type')`; используйте `.data('type')`
 * вместо сборки массива mas можно сразу элемент собирать.
 * вероятный признак говнокода - `if () {} else if {if()}`
 * много повторяющегося кода.

Comment: @eicto спасибо и на том.
но я никак не мог избавить от ифов (

Comment: используйте шаблоны mapping, это ассоциативный массивы устанавливающие соответствия одних данных другим, но возможно и это будет сложно, скорее всего сама задача решена неверно. в общем это просто признак, если `if else if else if else if`, то скорее всего вы делаете что-то не то. В общем, рекомендация -  когда у вас там вылезет баг, который вы будете два дня ловить, просто вспомните что я говорил по этому поводу.

Comment: @eicto Здравствуйте!
Можете мне помочь в одном вопросе ? (если есть время)
очень нужно